# Highcharts data labels overlapping columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with data labels overlapping columns in my chart.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0), 169], 
                  [Date.UTC(2013, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0), 176], 
                  [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0), 470], 
                  [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0), 346], 
                  [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0), 252], 
                  [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0), 138]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

You can see an exmaple here: http://jsfiddle.net/J6WvR/1/

My chart should have fixed height and I don't understand why the largest column height cannot be calculated to fit its data label. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it necessary to have a fixed height? bcoz if you remove height from container then it should work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to official API documentation: [overflow property](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow)

> To display data labels outside the plot area, set crop to **false** and overflow to "**none**".

```
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                crop: false,
                overflow: 'none'
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try max for yAxis,

calculate maximum value from you data and add some cushion say 100 to it and set it as max for yAxis

```
yAxis:{
                max: 600,
            },
```

updating your fiddle with max for yAxis at http://jsfiddle.net/J6WvR/3/

hope this will be of use for you

Answer (score 0):

One option is to move the position of the labels. e.g. this will move them inside the bars:

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 20,
                color:'white'
            }
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TBfLS/

An alternative is to manually set the max y value to make room for the label:

```
  yAxis: {
        max: 600,
        endOnTick: false
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2AhVT/

Hopefully one of these options will help.

A third (and probably better) option was posted by Ivan Chau.

Answer (score 0):

after enabling dataSorting highchart it is not showing data label properly in stacked column chart

[image: reference image]